# não consigo pegar valor do input javascript

Tags: javascript

não estou conseguindo pegar valor do input

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="numero">olaa</input>
  <button onclick="enviar()">mostrar</button>
  <p id="par"></p>


  <script>
    var par = "";

    var numero = document.getElementById('numero').value;

    function enviar() {
      par = document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = numero.value;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode pegar o valor do `input` através do `document.getElementById('numero').value`. Como pode ver, o `id` deve ser o do input, essa parte você fez certo, faltou apenas colocar dentro do função `enviar`. Já o `.innerHTML`, não. Ele serve para alterar o conteúdo da página. Para fazer isso, faça o seguinte: `document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = "conteúdo para aparecer"`.

E também você colocou "olaa" no input, ele não funciona dessa forma, por isso retirei no código a seguir.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="numero"></input>
  <button onclick="enviar()">mostrar</button>
  <p id="par"></p>

<script>
   function enviar() {
      var numero = document.getElementById('numero').value;
      document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = numero;
   }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, mas o meu problemas maior foi o seguinte: coloquei o input despois capturei numa variavel e depois coloquei para quando o botao fosse clicado ele alerta a variavel mas sempre dava: NAN ou undefined ou 0 ou nada

Comment: Sim, acontecia isso antes pois a atribuição da variável "numero" está fora da função enviar. Ou seja, você não "capturava" o valor do input.